# how can I view the response after xmlrpc has thrown http.client.badstatusline

Tags: python-3.x, perl, https, xml-rpc

I'm trying to hookup to an old perl based xmlrpc server. but It doesn't return any headers with its response so my python3 client chokes on it. I've tried catching the exception but it seems to be to deep in there for me to do anything about it.

I know it isn't broken, I can call it with perl, just not with python. I'm trying to change the server to include a http header but havn't been able to figure that out yet. I'm also thinking about  trying it with sockets but that seems like it would be real messy and fragile.

the perl that works :

```
use Frontier::Client;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $c = new Frontier::Client( url => 'https://somesite:666/RPC2', debug => 1);
$c->{'ua'}->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0, SSL_verify_mode => 0);
my $q = $c->call('ping');
```

the python that doesn't:

```
import ssl
import xmlrpc.client

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://somesite.com:666/RPC2', verbose=True)
x = s.ping()
```

and the resulting stack trace:

```
send: b'POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: somesite.com:666\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\nUser-Agent: Python-xmlrpc/3.6\r\nContent-Length: 98\r\n\r\n'
send: b"<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<methodCall>\n<methodName>ping</methodName>\n<params>\n</params>\n</methodCall>\n"
reply: '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_xml.py", line 12, in <module>
    x = s.ping()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1167, in single_request
    resp = http_conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1346, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

there must be some way for me to get the response from that exception, I'm just not sure how.